# Change image layout orientation

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp

I am displaying the images here..they are arranging in vertical way by generating 
 dynamically...But i want it in horizontal pattern...how can i do this?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
         if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
          // System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                String finalImage="Images/"+listOfFiles[i].getName();
            out.print("<img src='"+finalImage+"' width='200' height='200'/>");    
             //out.println(finalImage);
         }
 }
```

Comment: This relates to a CSS problem but you haven't posted the CSS itself, we need to see that before we can help you :)

Comment: sorry Kyle..Scince i didny use any css in this work i didnt mention that...I will make it in proper way from next time...sorry dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting them in their own div instead:

```
for (...) {
  out.print("<div style=\"float:left;\">");
  out.print("<img ...");
  out.print("</div>");
}
```

and when the images are finished, clear the float:

```
out.print("<div style=\"clear:both;\"/>");
```

much better to do all that with an MVC framework though, if you're using JSP, like Spring and taglibs rather than raw output

Comment: sorry! try putting each image in its own div. Have updated the answer to show that